# Why can I not do arithmetic on a cast of a void pointer?

Tags: c

```
void foo(void *ptr, int numBytes)
{
    (char*)ptr += numBytes;
}
```

This doesn't compile in C. I know the alternative.  But why does this not work? What is the problem?

Comment: The same reason why `5 += 7` fails.

Comment: Because you aren't using GCC.  More precisely, the C standard outlaws it because the size of the thing pointed at is not known and pointer arithmetic depends on the size of the object.  You also can't increment function pointers.  GCC does allow arithmetic on `void *` (treating it as synonymous with `char *` for this purpose), but it is an extension of the standard and more often used by accident than with intent.  Avoid arithmetic on `void *`!

Comment: Actually, my previous comment -- thank goodness it is a comment -- is mostly tangential to the question; it details why `ptr += numBytes;` is not acceptable to compilers other than GCC (and probably clang in its GCC-compatibility mode), rather than why the cast does not work.  The information is valid, but slightly off-target.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**The problem**

The problem is that `(char*)ptr` will not yield an *lvalue*, meaning that the value cannot be modified - one can see it as a temporary result of the cast, the cast will yield a *rvalue* of type `char*`.

It's semantically the same as if you'd have the below example, a cast yields a temporary value, such a value cannot be assigned a new value.

```
int x = 123;

(float)x += 0.12f; /* (1), illegal                                     */
                   /*  ^-- sementically equivalent to `123.f += 0.12f` */
```

---

**Solution**

In your question you have stated that you already know a workaround to this problem, but I'd like to explicitly write the solution to show how one can modify the value of `ptr` even when casts yields non-modifiable values.

1. Take the address of your *pointer to void*,
2. cast this address to a *pointer to pointer to char*,
3. dereference that pointer, yielding a *pointer to char*,
4. modify this yield *lvalue* as if the original `void*` was of type `char*`

```
*((char**)&ptr) += numbytes; // make `ptr` move forward `numbytes`
```

( **Note**: When dereferencing a pointer you get an *lvalue*, otherwise it would be impossible to change the value of the *pointed to* value located at an address stored in a pointer. )

Answer (score 4):

That's because

`(char*)ptr` is not an lvalue.

Try this instead:

```
void foo(void *ptr, int numBytes)
{
    char* p = (char*)ptr;
    p += numBytes;
}
```

**Update**

A brief explanation of various value types can be found at [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category). This talks about value types in C++ but the core ideas translate to C.

For the purpose of this discussion,

> An lvalue is an expression that identifies a non-temporary object or a non-member function.

You can take the address of an lvalue and assign to a different value.

Example:

```
int i;
int* p = &i;
i = 20;
```

In contrast,

> A prvalue ("pure" rvalue) is an expression that identifies a temporary object (or a subobject thereof) or is a value not associated with any object.

The literal `42` is an rvalue. You cannot do:

```
int* p = &42;
42 = 53;
```

In this line,

```
    char* p = (char*)ptr;
```

an lvalue (`p`) is created from `(char*)ptr`. Hence, it is possible to use:

```
    p += numBytes;
```

Comment: Could you give a bit more detail on this?  From the eyes of a beginner, the two seem identical.  It just looks like you used a temporary intermediate value and it magically works.

Comment: there's a misleading link to the C++ language reference in this answer, and it also mentions "member functions", which are nonexistent in C. Don't mix or make others confuse C and C++, that's harmful.

Answer (score 3):

On the left side of an `=`, you need an `lvalue`. But `(char*)ptr` is not an lvalue.