# C - expression must be a modifiable lvalue

Tags: c, pointers, void-pointers

I'm confused why my compiler is throwing an error in the following condition:

```
void funcExample (void * p_Buf, uint16_t len) 
{
    uint16_t i;

    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        otherFunc (((uint8_t *)p_Buf)++); //error = expression must be a modifiable lvalue
    }
}
```

but if I cast prior to pass to otherFunc, it's fine because no problem incrementing a non-void pointer:

```
void funcExample (void * p_Buf, uint16_t len) 
{
    uint16_t i;
    uint8_t * p_Buf_8bit;

    p_Buf_8bit = (uint8_t *) p_Buf;   

    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        otherFunc (p_Buf_8bit++); 
    }
}
```

can't the void pointer be incremented once cast? am i missing something fundamental here?

Comment: Not identical, but *very* [**similar question here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002044/why-can-i-not-do-arithmetic-on-a-cast-of-a-void-pointer).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cast operators in c:

> 6.5.4. p5 Preceding an expression by a parenthesized type name converts the value of the
>   expression to the named type. **This construction is called a cast. 104)** A cast that specifies
>   no conversion has no effect on the type or value of an expression.
>
> **104) A cast does not yield an lvalue.** Thus, a cast to a qualified type has the same effect as a cast to the
>   unqualified version of the type

But the unary operator `++` requires an lvalue as stated:

> 6.5.3.1. p1 The operand of the prefix increment or decrement operator shall have atomic, qualified,
>   or unqualified real or pointer type, **and shall be a modifiable lvalue.**

Therefore you can do:

```
p_Buf = ( uint8_t* )p_Buf + 1 ;
```

Where `p_Buf` is lvalue and `( uint8_t* )p_Buf` is rvalue.

Let me just note that in your second example you don't cast( as you said ), but you declare a uint8_t pointer. Then when you use `++` on it you don't perform any casts( because it has the correct type ) and the operation is valid.

Comment: You are converting your `void` pointer to `uint8_t` instead of pointer to it.

Comment: @Seprum No I am not. You might have seen an old edit. refresh the page.

Comment: thank you for the response and standard ref. and yes, an assignment not a cast in the second.

Answer (score 1):

Incrementing a `void` pointer in `C` is bad idea. Most compilers don't even let it to be compiled. Use this instead:

```
p_Buf = (uint8_t*)p_Buf + 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer @2501 posted is absolutely correct, but doesn't explain why the standard requires an *lvalue* for post-increment. The basic reason is that you need an *lvalue* (variable or memory location) for post-increment to perform its increment.

When you cast `p_Buf` to an `uint8_t*` type, you've created an *rvalue* in C. In simple terms, *rvalues* represent transient values that can be passed to functions, assigned to variables, etc. Post-increment returns the original value and then updates the variable or memory location where the value was stored, incrementing it. Because they only exist for the duration of the expression, *rvalues* cannot be updated, and post-increment cannot operate on them. Thus the problem with

```
    otherFunc (((uint8_t *)p_Buf)++); //error = expression must be a modifiable lvalue
```

is that the `((uint8_t *)pBuf)` is just an *rvalue* expression with no actual storage location.  In effect, the cast means that you're only using the value of `p_Buf`, and no longer directly using the variable `p_Buf`.

On the other hand, when you assign the cast to a variable:

```
p_Buf_8bit = (uint8_t *) p_Buf;
```

then the variable `p_Buf_8bit` is an *lvalue*, which represent a variable or memory location. This can be post-incremented, making this a perfectly well-formed statement in C:

```
    otherFunc (p_Buf_8bit++);
```

Comment: thank you for the additional explanation -> this really helps. the issue is the temporary/transient nature of the cast (rvalue vs lvalue). thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The result of a cast operation is an rvalue, not an lvalue. `((uint8_t *)p_Buf)++` is simply not legal C code.